# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint while updating field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a gridview i that adding the row with text box and adding the data which is successfully done.. But when i am update a field Email it is showing the error.. Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint while updating field

```
function: Update_U_Anonymoususerdetails

int InsId=0, UserId=0,UserInstLink=0,UserCreditRecord=0;
                SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(Conn);
                Cn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label Id = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblId") as Label;
                    TextBox Name = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
                    TextBox MName = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtMName") as TextBox;
                    TextBox LName = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLName") as TextBox;
                    TextBox Degree = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtDegree") as TextBox;
                    TextBox Title = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
                    TextBox Email = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox;
                    TextBox Institution = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtInstitution") as TextBox;
                    if (Name.Text.Trim() != null && Name.Text.Trim() !="")
                    {
                        int AId = 0;
                        if (Id != null)
                            AId = Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text);
                        else
                            AId = 0;                       
                        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateOtherAuthors", Cn);
                        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlParameter InID = new SqlParameter("@uiID", SqlDbType.Int);                      
                        InID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        Cmd.Parameters.Add(InID);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", MName.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Degree", Degree.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Institution", Institution.Text);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", AId);
                        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseId", CaseId);                        
                        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        UserId = int.Parse(Cmd.Parameters["@uiID"].Value.ToString());//getting error in this line first

                    }
                    if (Institution.Text.Trim() != null && Institution.Text.Trim() != "")
                    {

                       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddInstitution", Cn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlParameter oParam = new SqlParameter("@Institution", Institution.Text.ToString());
                        SqlParameter InID = new SqlParameter("@InID",SqlDbType.Int);
                        oParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        InID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(oParam);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(InID);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        InsId = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@InID"].Value.ToString());

                    }
                   UserInstLink= UserInstutionLink(UserId, InsId);// I am getting the error in this line
                   UserCreditRecord = UserCreditRecordID(UserInstLink, Name.Text, MName.Text, LName.Text, Degree.Text, Title.Text);
                   AssignContentManagementPrivileges(UserId,CaseId);
                   CreateCaseCredits(InsId, CaseId, UserCreditRecord);

                }
                Cn.Close();


store procedure i am using

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateOtherAuthors]

(
@Name nvarchar(50),
@MName nvarchar(50),
@LName nvarchar(50),
@Degree nvarchar(50),
@Title nvarchar(50),
@Email nvarchar(50),
@Institution nvarchar(50),
@Id int,
@CaseId int,
@uiID int output

)

AS BEGIN
Declare @SameId nvarchar(50)
if(@Id='0')
begin
INSERT INTO tbl_AuthorDetails VALUES(@Name,@Degree,@Title,@Email,@Institution,@CaseId,@LName,@MName)
    Select @Id=COUNT(Email) from [User] where Email=@Email
    if(@Id=0)
    begin
    exec CreateOtherAuthorsAccount @Name,@LName,@MName,@Degree,@Email
    end
end
else
begin

set @SameId=(Select (Email) from  tbl_AuthorDetails where Id=@Id)
if(@SameId = @Email)
  Update  tbl_AuthorDetails set Name=@Name,Degree=@Degree,Title=@Title,Email=@Email,Institution=@Institution,LName=@LName,MName=@MName where Id=@Id
else
 begin
    INSERT INTO tbl_AuthorDetails VALUES(@Name,@Degree,@Title,@Email,@Institution,@CaseId,@LName,@MName)
    Update  tbl_AuthorDetails set  CaseId=NULL  where Id=@Id
    exec CreateOtherAuthorsAccount @Name,@LName,@MName,@Degree,@Email
    end
end

END
set @uiID= (Select ID from [User] where Email=@Email)  
RETURN @uiID
```

calling the function:

```
objGetBaseCase.Update_U_Anonymoususerdetails(GridView1, Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because a record with same `email` already exists in the database. And the database has a constraint on the email field that each entry in this field should be *unique* in the table you are inserting data into.

**EDIT:** If this data is provided by a user, then you need to catch this *exception* and show a message to the user "A record with same email address already exists in the system." And allow him/her to re-enter data for the email field.

Comment: Use a different email address

Comment: @connell watkins: if user don't know is that mail id is already in the date base then???

Comment: @Abuhurera Ansari: Then catch this exception and show an error message to the user "A user with same email address already exists."

Comment: it happened with stored procedure that select from the database

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you can check to see if the email already exists:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_AuthorDetails where Email = @Email)
BEGIN
    Update  tbl_AuthorDetails set Name=@Name,Degree=@Degree,Title=@Title,Email=@Email,Institution=@Institution,LName=@LName,MName=@MName where Id=@Id
END
```

Comment: If not exists, update? Shouldn't it be if not exist, insert, else update?

Comment: @TipX - Yes - You are checking whether the email exists before you update an existing record to contain it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I read this as "If there is no record, update THAT record (which doesn't exist)", I missed the part where you updated where id = @id, not based on email.

Comment: @ Tipx and James: I used your code but i am getting the same prob. its not yet fixed i am getting the error in  objGetBaseCase.Update_U_Anonymoususerdetails(GridView1, Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0])); line again

Comment: I really not sure. As the other posts have said, you are inserting some value into a field that already contains that field. The exception shoudl give more details of the tables involved. You would also try manually inserting the data into the database to see what happens.

Comment: I am able to update the email upto 3 time, if i am trying to update the email more than 3 time i am getting the same error